# Flutter google sign in stay logged in

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have implemented the firebase auth google sign in but how do i able to stay logged in after the app is closed, i even put this line `await _auth.currentUser()` but still not working. Below is my login code.

**LoginPage.dart** **(OLD)**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

//Google provider
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:flutter_facebook_login/flutter_facebook_login.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth_buttons/flutter_auth_buttons.dart';

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
String _email;
String _password;
GoogleSignInAccount _currentUser;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount account) 
{
  setState(() {
    _currentUser = account;
  });
  if (_currentUser != null) {
    //_handleGetContact();
  }
});
_googleSignIn.signInSilently();
}

//google sign in
GoogleSignIn googleAuth = new GoogleSignIn();

//Facebook sign in
FacebookLogin fbLogin = new FacebookLogin();

Future<FirebaseUser> _testSignInWithGoogle() async {
final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
    await googleUser.authentication;
final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
  accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
  idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
);
final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
assert(user.email != null);
assert(user.displayName != null);
assert(!user.isAnonymous);
assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

print('Signed in as ${user.displayName}');
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');

return await _auth.currentUser();
}

void _facebookLogin() async {
var facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
var facebookLoginResult =
    await facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email', 
'public_profile']);

 switch (facebookLoginResult.status) {
  case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
    print("Error");
    onLoginStatusChanged(false);
    break;
  case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
    print("CancelledByUser");
    onLoginStatusChanged(false);
    break;
  case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
    print("LoggedIn");
    onLoginStatusChanged(true);

    FacebookAccessToken myToken = facebookLoginResult.accessToken;
    AuthCredential credential= 
FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken: myToken.token);
    try {
      final FirebaseUser user = await 
FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

      //Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: 
(context) => DiscoverPage()));
      print('Signed in as ${user.displayName}');
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Facebook signin error: " + e.toString());
    }
    break;
}
}

bool isLoggedIn = false;

void onLoginStatusChanged(bool isLoggedIn) {
setState(() {
  this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn;
});
}


}
}
```

**LoginPage.dart** **(NEW)**

```
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
bool loading = false;

bool isLoggedIn = false;

void onLoginStatusChanged(bool isLoggedIn) {
setState(() {
  this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn;
});
}

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
isSignedIn();
}

void isSignedIn() async {
setState(() {
  loading = true;
});

isLoggedIn = await _googleSignIn.isSignedIn();

if (isLoggedIn) {
  Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
}

setState(() {
  loading = false;
});
}
}
```

I have to add this code in order to stay signed in. By the way, how do i able to make the same for Facebook?

Answer (score 3):

Check the [google_sign_in example](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_sign_in/example/lib/main.dart) , the snippet below may be the key to solve your problem.

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount account) {
      setState(() {
        _currentUser = account;
      });
      if (_currentUser != null) {
        _handleGetContact();
      }
    });
    _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
  }
```

I've implemented and tested it, and it works as expected.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering my question but still not working. May i ask where should i put the snippet? Should it be in the loginpage or homepage? Thanks

Comment: Put it in the initialized method of the page which you use google sign in. For example, If you use google sign in the login page and the root is StatefulWidget, just put it into `initState()`

Comment: Sorry that i have updated my code and didn't tell you. Is that correct?

Comment: Almost, don't you need to assign the `scopes` parameter when you create `GoogleSignIn` instance? I found that more than one `GoogleSignInAccount` instances in your code. Probably, you should use the non-null `_currentUser` to get the `GoogleSignInAuthentication` stuff instead of signing in again.

Comment: The scopes you mean this? `GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: <String>[
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
  ],
);`. Been stucked with this stay logged in for some time, is it the route problem? Could you help me check the code? Thanks

Comment: I've gone through your code. like I said above, you should have only one `GoogleSignIn` instance. Do you test if it can login successfully even though you need to enter the email and password every time? Once you login successfully, the login state can be kept for a period of time. Furthermore, check this snippet: https://gist.github.com/SeanZom/261fa991b925c6336075da98cdb30c05, I extracted the `GoogleSignIn` part from your code and tested it already.

Comment: I'm using other method and it's working, above code updated but this is only for google sign in. How do i able to make it work with facebook?

Answer (score 2):

```
Future googleSignIn() async {
try {
  GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );

  FirebaseUser _user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
  assert(_user.email != null);
  assert(_user.displayName != null);
  assert(!_user.isAnonymous);
  assert(await _user.getIdToken() != null);


    DatabaseServices(uid:_user.uid,email: _user.email)
        .updateUserData(_user.displayName,_user.photoUrl);

  print("signed in " + _user.displayName + "\n" + _user.photoUrl);

  return _user;
} catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
  return null;
}
```

}

Comment: `GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential`API is changed to `GoogleAuthProvider.credential`

Answer (score 0):

I personally haven't tried this after the release of flutter in stable channel but you could just store the user info obtained from the auth tokens.

Also take a look at this: https://medium.com/flutterpub/flutter-how-to-do-user-login-with-firebase-a6af760b14d5