# _googleSignIn.signInSilently() is not working

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I have copy pasted the whole code from https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in#-example-tab- but still I am getting the following error on _googleSignIn.signInSilently()

```
Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(sign_in_required, com.google.GIDSignIn, The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.GIDSignIn error -4.)))
```

Please have a look into below mentioned code snippet for main.dart file

```
// Copyright 2019 The Flutter Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert' show json;

import "package:http/http.dart" as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: <String>[
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
  ],
);

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Google Sign In',
      home: SignInDemo(),
    ),
  );
}

class SignInDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => SignInDemoState();
}

class SignInDemoState extends State<SignInDemo> {
  GoogleSignInAccount _currentUser;
  String _contactText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount account) {
      setState(() {
        _currentUser = account;
      });
      if (_currentUser != null) {
        _handleGetContact();
      }
    });
    _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
  }

  Future<void> _handleGetContact() async {
    setState(() {
      _contactText = "Loading contact info...";
    });
    final http.Response response = await http.get(
      'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections'
      '?requestMask.includeField=person.names',
      headers: await _currentUser.authHeaders,
    );
    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      setState(() {
        _contactText = "People API gave a ${response.statusCode} "
            "response. Check logs for details.";
      });
      print('People API ${response.statusCode} response: ${response.body}');
      return;
    }
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
    final String namedContact = _pickFirstNamedContact(data);
    setState(() {
      if (namedContact != null) {
        _contactText = "I see you know $namedContact!";
      } else {
        _contactText = "No contacts to display.";
      }
    });
  }

  String _pickFirstNamedContact(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    final List<dynamic> connections = data['connections'];
    final Map<String, dynamic> contact = connections?.firstWhere(
      (dynamic contact) => contact['names'] != null,
      orElse: () => null,
    );
    if (contact != null) {
      final Map<String, dynamic> name = contact['names'].firstWhere(
        (dynamic name) => name['displayName'] != null,
        orElse: () => null,
      );
      if (name != null) {
        return name['displayName'];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
    try {
      await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _handleSignOut() => _googleSignIn.disconnect();

  Widget _buildBody() {
    if (_currentUser != null) {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            leading: GoogleUserCircleAvatar(
              identity: _currentUser,
            ),
            title: Text(_currentUser.displayName ?? ''),
            subtitle: Text(_currentUser.email ?? ''),
          ),
          const Text("Signed in successfully."),
          Text(_contactText ?? ''),
          RaisedButton(
            child: const Text('SIGN OUT'),
            onPressed: _handleSignOut,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: const Text('REFRESH'),
            onPressed: _handleGetContact,
          ),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text("You are not currently signed in."),
          RaisedButton(
            child: const Text('SIGN IN'),
            onPressed: _handleSignIn,
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Google Sign In'),
        ),
        body: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
          child: _buildBody(),
        ));
  }
}
```

I want to user firebase as my backend. But before doing so this itself is not working for me.

I could see [Flutter google sign in stay logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54213860/flutter-google-sign-in-stay-logged-in) : here also they are using the same technique.

Answer (score 1):

According to the package requirements:

> To access Google Sign-In, you'll need to make sure to register your application (with firebase).
>
> You don't need to include the google-services.json file in your app unless you are using Google services that require it. You do need to enable the OAuth APIs that you want, using the Google Cloud Platform API manager. For example, if you want to mimic the behavior of the Google Sign-In sample app, you'll need to enable the Google People API.
>
> Make sure you've filled out all required fields in the console for OAuth consent screen. Otherwise, you may encounter APIException errors.

Comment: Yes, I had gone through that  and done all the requirements.

Comment: I have tested on demo app and sample worked successfully with no issues. You might need to ensure 1. you have registered app with firebase 2. your have enabled people api for the same project on your google console. 3. you have added the people api contact scopes to the oauth consent screen. 4. you can sign in first time 5. app requests for permissions 6. you consent to all. 7. it displays the current logged in user first time. 8. restarting the app should be able able to sign in silently.

Answer (score -1):

That error means there are no auth token in the keychain, I faced it once and solve with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48741071/12880676), I copy and send the code I used below, also you can check other solutions from that thread.

```
if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() == true{
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
}
else{
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}
```